# Hakyll: enabling pandoc extensions?

Tags: haskell, pandoc, hakyll

I wanted to enable the [Ext_autolink_bare_uris pandoc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.10.0.4/docs/Text-Pandoc-Options.html) extension for Hakyll posts. I followed the instructions given [here](https://nickcharlton.net/posts/custom-pandoc-options-hakyll-4.html), and everything seems to be working... except that extension! The bare URI's in posts are not transformed into a link. Everything else seems to function as normal. Here's the code in `site.hs`:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import           Text.Pandoc.Options

...

customPandocCompiler :: Compiler (Item String)
customPandocCompiler =
  let customExtensions = [Ext_autolink_bare_uris]
      defaultExtensions = writerExtensions defaultHakyllWriterOptions
      newExtensions = foldr S.insert defaultExtensions customExtensions
      writerOptions = defaultHakyllWriterOptions {
                        writerExtensions = newExtensions
                      }
  in pandocCompilerWith defaultHakyllReaderOptions writerOptions
```

The `customPandocCompiler` is used in all the relevant places. The code compiles normally, but does not yield the desired effect. Can anyone help me discover why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what input/output are you expecting? about bare_uris extension: `Makes all absolute URIs into links, even when not surrounded by pointy braces` (from the MANUAL)

Comment: Well, the input is an absolute URL in a markdown file, and the output I expected was that absolute URL, but clickable, in the HTML output. Instead what I get is the URL enclosed in `<p></p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit old now, but maybe this will help someone.

Newer Hakyll releases use [Pandoc 2.x](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.0) which changed a lot of things (see [PR #557](https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll/pull/557/files) especially). Notably the `Set` model for extensions is gone, in favour of custom types.

Anyway, here's a fairly customised setup that works well for us - disabling one default reader extension, and adding a few extra ones. There's probably a neater way of doing this still.

```
customRenderPandoc :: Item String -> Compiler (Item String)
customRenderPandoc = renderPandocWith customReaderOptions defaultHakyllWriterOptions
    where customReaderOptions = def { readerExtensions = extraReaderExts <> customReaderExts }
          extraReaderExts = extensionsFromList [Ext_auto_identifiers, Ext_ascii_identifiers, Ext_emoji, Ext_backtick_code_blocks]
          customReaderExts = disableExtension Ext_implicit_figures $ pandocExtensions
```

Note also I found it's not always obvious (nor typesafe) which extensions are reader and which writer. I guess some can be both... but check you've put yours in the right place as it's an easy mistake.